# Adding a columns according to rows found by str.contains(). pandas

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, contains

How to add a column according to the value found with str.contains? I am looking for names of men and adding a gender.

```
   df[df.loc[:,'name'].str.contains("John|Jon")]['gender'] = 'male'
```

I think this should work, but then:

```
df
```

returns df without columns. What is the best way to do these kind of changes?
Thank you

Comment: I think this line should be: `df[df.loc[:,'name'].str.contains("John|Jon"),'gender'] = 'male'` it looks like you are doing chained assignment which may or may not work, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=chain%20indexing#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["John|Jon", "ABC"], "age":[34, 45]})
df["gender"] = "unknown"
df["gender"][df["name"].str.contains("John")] = "male"
```

Comment: You asnwer changes all cells of selected row into "male". The change should happen only to "gender"